# Can I use auto apn in mbimcli?

Tags: debian, wwan

I have a running configuration file on debian 12: `/etc/mbim-network.conf`
It consists only of those 2 lines:

```
PROXY=yes
APN=internet.telekom
```

Is there a possibility to set the APN to autodiscover?